Macro for commenting multiple lines not working
The macro for commenting multiple lines (Command + Shift + [) has stopped working in my TexShop.  I recently updated TexShop to Version 5.44 but can't say for sure if this coincided exactly with that update.  Interestingly, the macro to uncomment multiple lines (Command + Shift + ]) still works.
Has anyone else experienced this?  Any solution to it?
Thanks for your help!

As far as I can see, in version 5.44 the shorthand for commenting selected lines is Command-/.
For uncommenting selected lines it's still Command-Shift-] (curiously marked Command-} in the menu).

That's it! Thanks!

This is a bug in the English localization which will be fixed in the next version. Write me directly if you are need an immediate fix.
